# Masonry style responsive layouts

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

Basically I want to lay out several unequal width/height DIVs that fit together in a masonry style layout.

I have used the jQuery Masonry plugin - which does what I want - to an extent.

My specific requirement is that I want to define exactly which DIVS appear and in what position on the page. The only time they would change position is when the browser is resized - in which case another (predefined) layout is applied.

So essentially I would have "layouts" for different screen sizes. The job of the plugin would be to ensure the items appear in a masonry style layout, i.e. without any gaps.

I've looked at several similar plugins but can't find any that will allow me to define fixed positions for items. They are all designed to automatically shuffle the items.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how I can go about this?

Comment: Would it be possible to use css media query’s?

Comment: Read about `@media-queries`. This is exactly what they are designed for

Comment: But would media queries alone solve the problem? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

[Salvattore](http://salvattore.com/) is a very nice Masonry like library and it has full support for media queries so maybe you can create some layouts using media queries.